# How to add widgets on GUI developed with Glade?

Tags: application-development, quickly, glade

I am using Quickly and Glade for the first time. I want to add certain widgets such as label and buttons on viewport via python code. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. If you haven't already loaded the glade file the load it with:

```
builder = gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("/path/to/file")
```

Replace "/path/to/file" with the path to the glade file. You can then get the container like the viewport:

```
viewport = builder.get_object("nameOfViewport")
```

Replace "nameOfViewport" with what you named it in glade. You can then add the widget using the view ports add() method:

```
viewport.add(nameOfWidget)
```

Replace "nameOfWidget" with the name of the widget you want to add.

Edit: Make sure you initialize the widget with something like

```
nameOfWidget = gtk.Label()
```

for a label widget.

Comment: Hii i tried with it, giving error as, TypeError: Expected Gtk.Widget, but got GObjectMeta

Comment: When adding the widget you need to either initialize it  using something like "label = gtk.Label()" and then add label to the viewport or just "viewport.add(gtk.Label())" but I would reccomend the first method.